# Jquery - Style the other li element by cliking li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**How to add or remove css for other li element.**

how can i change the back ground color for li by Click the li tag.

change the Back ground color for the particular (clicked li ) tag other change to gray - Change need to taken inside the particular UL not all UL tag.

Note : ul class all have to keep the same name

```
    <div id ="divid">
<div>
     <ul class="togle" data-id="1">
      <li class="myview active> one <li>
      <li class="myview > two <li>
      <li class="myview > three <li>
     <ul>
    </div>
    <div>
     <ul class="togle" data-id="2">
      <li class="myview > one <li>
      <li class="myview > two <li>
      <li class="myview active> three <li>
    <ul>
    </div>
    ....
    .....
    .....
</div>
```

like have more..

JS :

```
var element = $('#divid');
element.on('click', '.togle', function(e) {
        //e.preventDefault();
        console.log("========");    

       $('#divid .togle li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
```

css:

```
.myview {
background-color: #eee;
}
.myview .active {
background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

Comment: `$('#divid ...')` isn't referencing anything.

Comment: Use [`$elm.siblings('li')`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Comment: css fix: `.myview.active {`  (no space).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have stated, you need to use [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to target only the items inside the current `ul`.

Also, your CSS is a bit off and won't trigger the highlight you expect. You should be using the CSS rule:

```
.myview.active
```

Instead you have:

```
.myview .active
```

That extra space is important, when you write it without the space it means you are targeting an element with both of those classes. With the space it means you are targeting an child element with class `active` where the parent is of class `myview`.

There's a running example below that should work as expected.

```js
$(".togle .myview").click(function() {
  var self = $(this);
  self.siblings("li.myview").removeClass("active");
  self.addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.myview {
  background-color: #eee;
}
.myview.active {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="togle" data-id="1">
  <li class="myview active"> one </li>
  <li class="myview"> two </li>
  <li class="myview"> three </li>
</ul>
<ul class="togle" data-id="2">
  <li class="myview"> one </li>
  <li class="myview"> two </li>
  <li class="myview active"> three </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

JS:

```
$('.togle li').click(function(){
  $(this).parent('ul').find('li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

CSS:

```
.togle li{
   background-color: #eeeeee;
}
.togle li.active{
   background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

Comment: I'd propose `find('li.active')`, it doesn't change the outcome, but it does look a bit clearer to me, as the intention to find the `li`s that are `active` is now blatantly obvious.

Comment: Yes. You are correct but its a basic code to solve the issue, later developer can modify it by using li.active, or checking either ul has any active li or select default/first li, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
$(".myview").click(function(){
    $(".togle").find(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your needs here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/to792rq2/), using `$(this)`you can access the clicked element properties.

The `toggleClass`is a useful Jquery method to add/remove a CSS class without knowing if the element has it or not.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <ul class="togle" data-id="1">
        <li class="myview active"> one </li>
        <li class=" myview">two</li>
        <li class="myview" > three </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
   <ul class=" togle " data-id="2 ">
        <li class="myview">one</li>
        <li class="myview" > two </li>
        <li class="myview active">three</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.myview').click(function (e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: No, why? Did you try the JSFiddle? Each `li ` is independent https://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/to792rq2/

Comment: Let me understand do you want the active one to not be clicked?

Comment: Thanks for your answer .. but this make click to active and click again to remove .. but need to remove the other by clicking one .. refer the ticked answer

Answer (score 0):

Use the following click event to remove all active classes and then add the active class only to the clicked.

```
$('.myview').click(function () {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/op9tyoyo/)